# Trying to scrape data from a website dicksmith.com.au

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

python 2.7.6, scrapy 0.24.6, website- dicksmith.com.au,OS- Linux(Ubuntu)
url(mobile site is easy) -
http://search.dicksmith.com.au/search?w=mobile+phone&ts=m

Sorry, guys I am new to scrapy. Thanks in advance

Code:

```
import scrapy

class PriceWatchItem( scrapy.Item ):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class PriceWatchSpider( CrawlSpider ):
    name = 'dicksmith'
    allowed_domains = ['dicksmith.com.au']
    start_urls = ['http://search.dicksmith.com.au/search']
    rules = [ Rule ( LinkExtractor( allow = ['?w=mobile+phone&ts=m']      ), 'parse_dickSmith' ) ]

    def parse_dickSmith( self, response ):
        dickSmith = PriceWatchItem()
        dickSmith['name'] = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
        return dickSmith
  #scrapy crawl dicksmith -o scraped_data.jason
```

ERROR:

```
File "pricewatch.py", line 10, in <module>
    class PriceWatchSpider( CrawlSpider ):
  File "pricewatch.py", line 14, in PriceWatchSpider
    rules = [ Rule ( LinkExtractor( allow = ['?w=mobile+phone&ts=m'] ), 'parse_dickSmith' ) ]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/linkextractors/lxmlhtml.py", line 94, in __init__
    deny_extensions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/linkextractor.py", line 46, in __init__
    self.allow_res = [x if isinstance(x, _re_type) else re.compile(x) for x in arg_to_iter(allow)]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to escape ? and +

Try this

```
reg = re.compile('\?w=mobile\+phone&ts=m')
rules = [ Rule ( LinkExtractor(allow = reg, 'parse_dickSmith' ) ]
```